# Finding the rank of a derivative matrix

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth with $f'(x) \not = 0$ for all $ x \in \{ x | f(x) = 0 \} = S$. I am then told that $Df$ has rank $1$ for all $ x \in S$

I can't see why this is true, could someone explain please? I figure that $Df$ is a $1 \times 2$ matrix, so should have rank $2$ as long as both elements are none zero.

Comment: you are using a wrong definition of matrix's rank

Comment: I have it as the maximum number of linearly independent columns - i just don't see why we know both columns are dependent.

Comment: Recall that the rank of $Df$ is the number of linearly independent columns or rows in your matrix /they coincide wether you calculate it using columns or rows).  In your case, there is only one row. Therefore the rank is at most $1$ but since you also have that the matrix is non-zero, it must be $1$.

Comment: I calculate it using columns, we have two columns - how can we conclude theya re not linearly independent? I see how they are non zero.

Comment: Because the rank using columns coincides with the rank using rows. And there is only one row.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that - why do they coincide?

Comment: You can find a full proof here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_.3D_row_rank

Comment: Also: each column is one number.  Any two (non-zero) numbers are multiples of each other.  So, the columns are always multiples of each other.  So, the rank is always at most $1$.